# Content-Type: application/vnd.com.runkeeper.User+json , what is the meaning?

Tags: rest

I have been looking at the [API](http://runkeeper.com/developer/healthgraph/example-api-calls#top) of the company Runkeeper and have been surprised to see this :

```
Content-Type: application/vnd.com.runkeeper.User+json
```

in their api calls. Does somebody know what is the purpose of it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing a vendor defined media type. The content type is an extension of `application/json`. This [post](http://blog.2partsmagic.com/restful-uri-design/) shows some sample uses of it. Most cases it is used for versioning the APIs.
Vendor defined media types are usually of the form `{type}/vnd.{company specific}+{subtype}`. Eg `application/vnd.basil.v1+json`